# Excel VBA file content is persistent despite KILL

Tags: excel, vba, ftp

I have an Excel VBA script that takes two files and performs a Relace function on one column. This all works fine if i step through it slowly. But if i run it without any breaks then it produces a file that still contains the characters that i replaced ?

I have added "Kill" file commands to ensure that i am creating new files, even my output file i am using a datestamp to ensure its a unique file then renaming it. But i then upload it to an FTP server as part of the script and when viewing what i have uploaded, it has the characters i removed ? even though when i view my output file before uploading, it doesnt ?????

```
Private Sub OutputFile()

Dim strNowDifferentiator As String
Dim strPath As String
Dim AgentStr As String
Dim AccessTypeLong As Long
Dim ProxyNameStr As String
Dim ProxyBypassStr As String
Dim FlagsLong As Long

Dim InternetSessionLong As Long
Dim ServiceLong As Long
Dim ContextLong As Long

Dim FTPSessionLong As Long
Dim FailIfExistsBool As Boolean
Dim FlagsAndAttributesLong As Long

Dim SomeThingLong As Long
Dim MyInternetHandleLong As Long
Dim MyFTPHandleLong As Long
Dim SomeInteger As Integer
Dim FTPSuccessBool As Boolean ' Did the FTP download work?

AgentStr = "GreenTreeTest" ' can be whatever
AccessTypeLong = 0 ' zero appears to work fine
ProxyNameStr = "" ' nul works fine here
ProxyBypassStr = "" ' nul works fine here
FlagsLong = 0 ' zero appears to work fine

MyInternetHandleLong = InternetOpen(AgentStr, AccessTypeLong, ProxyNameStr, ProxyBypassStr, FlagsLong)

' MsgBox MyInternetHandleLong

'MyInternetHandleLong is obtained above

ServiceLong = 1 ' this for the FTP service (2 = gopher, 3 = http)
FlagsLong = 0 ' 0 appears to work fine here
ContextLong = 0 ' 0 appears to work fine here

MyFTPHandleLong = InternetConnect(MyInternetHandleLong, "mercury.ingrammicro.com", 21, "CDW_PRICEFILE", "XXXXX", ServiceLong, FlagsLong, ContextLong)


strNowDifferentiator = Replace(Replace(Now(), "/", " "), ":", "")
strPath = "\\Sov-fs3\Departmental\Supply Chain\Feeds\"
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Call subUpdateProgressLabel("Producing the output file...")
'DeleteFile ("C:\temp\CDWFeed.csv")
DeleteFile (strPath & "CDWFeed.csv")

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output").Copy
'ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\temp\CDWFeed.csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=True
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=strPath & "CDWFeed" & strNowDifferentiator & ".csv", FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=True
ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False

Name strPath & "CDWFeed" & strNowDifferentiator & ".csv" As strPath & "CDWFeed.csv"

Call FtpDeleteFile(MyFTPHandleLong, "CDWFeed.csv")

Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Sheets("Output").Cells.Clear
Call subUpdateProgressLabel("Uploading file to Ingram fTP...")
'removed SHELL as doesnt work well within CITRIX
'Shell ("ftp -s:" & Chr(34) & "\\Sov-fs3\Departmental\Supply Chain\Feeds\script.txt" & Chr(34) & " mercury.ingrammicro.com")
Call FtpUpload("\\Sov-fs3\Departmental\Supply Chain\Feeds\CDWFeed.csv", "CDWFeed.csv", "mercury.ingrammicro.com", 21, "CDW_PRICEFILE", "XXXXXX")

End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It is not clear what `subUpdateProgressLabel` is performing?.Is it `Producing the output file...` or `Uploading file to Ingram fTP....   `. Also not clear why 
`Call FtpDeleteFile(MyFTPHandleLong, "CDWFeed.csv"` is used, if file name is  `"CDWFeed" & strNowDifferentiator & ".csv" `

Comment: hi, the below line of code renames the file back. i created it with a datestamp initially so to ensure the file system treated it as a new file.

Regards subUpdateProgressLabel , this simply updates a label on a form, nothing important.

Name strPath & "CDWFeed" & strNowDifferentiator & ".csv" As strPath & "CDWFeed.csv"